# How to make OpenERP portable with all its dependencies?

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I am working with OpenERP 7 on Ubuntu 12.04.
I want to run OpenERP in other linux machines without repeating steps mentioned in this [tutorial](http://help.openerp.com/question/2562/how-to-install-openerp-v70-on-ubuntu-1204-from-launchpad-repository/) . I want to make it portable.

I want just to copy and paste the OpenERP directory with all the dependencies ( Python files, Postgresql ..).
How can we do that ?

Comment: Why cant you write a python script for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use various builds directly available here : http://nightly.openerp.com

Comment: thanks [Parthiv](http://stackoverflow.com/users/216759/parthiv). I already knew about this site, I want to make a PORTABLE version, a folder which contains OpenERP files, Python files and Postgres files, exactly like what Django Bitnami does.
I found a [solution for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/greenopenerp/) , but I want to do that with Ubuntu

Comment: Bitnami also has openerp build with all available in one click, do you need anything other than that as well ?